# hiding a table row using checkox inside the row

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table which contains rows with a checkbox inside and some contents. The rows are created with PHP from a database.

This is the table:

```html
<table id="mytable">
   <th>checkbox</th>
   <th>Contents</th>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="hiderow()" checked/></td>
     <td>Content1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="hiderow()" checked/></td>
     <td>Content2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="hiderow()" checked/></td>
      <td>Content3</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="hiderow()" checked/></td>
     <td>Content4</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

As you can see, the checkboxes are checked.

What I want is that when I uncheck a checkbox, the row will be hidden. For example, if I uncheck the checkbox in the second row, the row containing a checkbox and Content2 will be hidden.

```html
<script>
function hiderow(){
    var i;
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");//get the table
    var rows = tab.getElementByTagName("tr");//get the table rows
 //loop through each row
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        var td = rows[i].getElementByTagName("td")[0];//get the first td inside the row
        var checkbox = td.getElementByTagName("input");//get the input inside the td
            if(checkbox.checked == true){
                tr[i].style.display ="block";
            }else{
                tr[i].style.display ="none";
                }
    }
}


</script>
```

I have tried this script but it doesn't work. Can you give me any ideas on whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** The `hiderow` method can be modified with event object:

```
function hiderow(event){
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.display ="none";  
}
```

The event object contains information of your parent node `tr` so just need to be make hidden it.

**Second:** And then add the `hiderow(event)` in the html `onchange` event as

```
onchange = "hiderow(event)
```

This event will be fired whenever the value of checkbox change.

> Final code snippet is as follows:

```html
<table id="mytable">
<th>checkbox</th>
<th>Contents</th>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked onchange = "hiderow(event)" /></td>
<td>Content1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked onchange = "hiderow(event)"/></td>
<td>Content2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked onchange = "hiderow(event)"/></td>
<td>Content3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked onchange = "hiderow(event)"/></td>
<td>Content4</td>
</tr>
<table>
<script>
function hiderow(event){
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.display ="none";    
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Rouge, Please check the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try it.

Comment: It displays error in the snippet Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: hiderow is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 66
}

Comment: It worked now. But is there a way to reverse the action?

Comment: Yes, Its possible. Get all element by using getElementByTag, then compare all the **tr** with current **tr**, if not matched then use **style.display ="block";**

Comment: Can I check if the checkbox is checked in with this?

Comment: Yes. You can use as **document.getElementByTagName("input").checked** to check it